# Populating C# datatable with refcursor values from an Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I'm looking to populate a datatable with the values of a refcursor parameter UserRole from a stored procedure "spValidateDBA" but it's giving me this error every time:

> Column 'UserRole' does not belong to table.

**C# code:-**

```
string sConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;User ID=sys;Password=system;DBA PRIVILEGE=sysdba";
        OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(sConnectionString);
        OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("spValidateDBA", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.CommandText = "spValidateDBA";
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
        myCommand.Parameters["UserId"].Value = txtUsrId.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserRole",OracleDbType.RefCursor, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserIdOut", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rolechk = false;
        string checkrole = "DBA";
       myConnection.Open();
       myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // Create the OracleDataAdapter
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);  // Trying to populate a DataTable with refcursor UserRole.
        if (myCommand.Parameters["UserIdOut"].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == txtUsrId.Text.ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                CustomMsgbox.Show("1", "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["UserRole"].ToString().ToUpper().Equals(checkrole)==true)//getting the error "Column 'UserRole' does not belong to table." here
                   {

                        CustomMsgbox.Show("\tLogin Successful..!!\t" + Environment.NewLine + "Welcome to DB Utilities Tool", "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");
                        DBA dba = new DBA();
                        dba.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                        rolechk = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                if (!rolechk)
                {

                    CustomMsgbox.Show("Insufficient privileges", "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");
                    myConnection.Close();
                }


        else
            CustomMsgbox.Show("Please enter correct User ID/Password", "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");

    }
```

**Stored procedure spValidateDBA**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
    UserId IN VARCHAR2,
UserRole OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
 UserIdOut OUT VARCHAR2)
  AS
BEGIN
select USERNAME into UserIdOut from DBA_USERS DU where DU.USERNAME=UserId;
OPEN UserRole FOR
select GRANTED_ROLE from DBA_USERS DU,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS DRP where DU.USERNAME=UserId AND DU.USERNAME=DRP.GRANTEE;
  END spValidateDBA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving only one column `GRANTED_ROLE` in the cursor query:

> OPEN UserRole FOR
>   select **GRANTED_ROLE** from DBA_USERS DU, .......

however you are trying to fetch an `UserRole` column from the cursor.

> if (dr["**UserRole**"].ToString().ToUp.........

There is not any column named `UserRole` there, you can only fetch `GRANTED_ROLE`.

Comment: Thanks mate for pointing out the error,you're a lifesaver.I was mistakingly considering the cursor name for the data table column name instead of the actual database column being fetched from the stored proc,thanks once again,truly appreciate your help..!!!